# Retriving and using the data from the database

Tags: java, sql, database, backend

On each from the database I'm retrieving any single user information from the database. Does it will be a good practice to store all the user information from the database in a list(while the application starts) and then to retrieve the user information from the list.

It might be a stupid question and not up to the Stackoverflow standard. It is just a doubt. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may or may not be good practice, and that would depend on how much user data you would need to store.  A good place to start reading would be on how Hibernate/ORM tools work.  Hibernate, among other things, effectively acts as a cache which could store your user objects.  Then, for user objects which you might need over a certain duration, you would not need to keep hitting the database.

Answer (score 0):

for single user if you are retrieving list it is bad practice bcz it impact to browser performance, if your really need more records, try to bring them with pagination it is good practice

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about a single user information, It can be equated to an Object in java.  A single User object can hold all the information about an user.  Hence rather than having the user info in a list and retrieving from that, It is a best practice to have the data in the single object.

It is not a good practice to have the data in a list for the scenario you are talking about.